# Why there is an additional blank page when export to pdf that is not shown in print preview on a report - Ms Access 2013?

Tags: ms-access, pdf, report, print-preview

I have a report in Ms Access that has 5 subreports in the detail section and number page in the page footer section. Between the 4th and 5th subreport there is a page break. all subreports and the detail section are set to property can grow and can shrink yes. The report width is 7.3 which considers the margin and should fit in a 8 1/2 x 11 page. And there is only one single line code for the report

```
Me.PageBreak.Visible = Me.Report1.Report.HasData
```

The question is why on print preview the report shows only two pages which is correct and when export to pdf, it would export with an additional blank page which didn't show on the print preview?

The additional blank page has a small gray rectangle on the top part.

Comment: Did you search topic "access report to pdf extra blank page"? Could be various causes - for one review https://forums.asp.net/t/1697307.aspx?Extra+blank+pages+added+to+report+when+saved+as+pdf